# Impala query - optimize a query to get the uniques for given key

Tags: sql, impala

I'm looking for ways to count unique users that have a specific pkey and also the count of unique users who didn't have that pkey.

Here is a sample table:

```
 userid |   pkey     | pvalue
------------------------------
   U1   |   x        | vx
   U1   |   y        | vy
   U1   |   z        | vz
   U2   |   y        | vy
   U3   |   z        | vz
   U4   |   null     | null
```

I get the expected results to get the unique users who has the pkey='y' and those who didn't using this query but turns out to be expensive:

```
WITH all_rows AS
  ( SELECT userid, 
           IF( pkey='y', pval, 'none' ) AS val,
           SUM( IF(pkey='y',1,0) ) AS has_key
   FROM some_table 
   GROUP BY userid, val)
SELECT val,
       count(distinct(userid)) uniqs
FROM all_rows
WHERE has_key=1
GROUP BY val
UNION ALL
SELECT 'no_key_set' val,
       count(distinct(userid)) uniqs
FROM all_rows a1 LEFT ANTI JOIN 
     all_rows a2 on (a1.userid = a2.userid and a2.has_key=1) 
GROUP BY val;

Results:

val        | uniqs
--------------------
vy         | 2
no_key_set | 2
```

I'm looking to avoid using any temp tables, so any better ways this can be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `EXPLAIN`, you can observe that most of the cost is spent on doing excessive `GROUP BY` aggregations rather than on using subqueries in your original query.

Here is a straightforward implementation

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT pkey, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM table
    WHERE pkey IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY pkey
), t2 AS (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS total_cnt
    FROM table
)
SELECT
    CONCAT('no_', pkey) AS pkey,
    (total_cnt - cnt) AS cnt
FROM t1, t2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t1
```

- `t1` gets a table of unique user count per pkey

  ```
  +------+-----+
  | pkey | cnt |
  +------+-----+
  | x    | 1   |
  | z    | 2   |
  | y    | 2   |
  +------+-----+
  ```
- `t2` gets the number of total unique users

  ```
  +-----------+
  | total_cnt |
  +-----------+
  | 4         |
  +-----------+
  ```
- we can use the result from `t2` to get the complement table of `t1`

  ```
  +------+-----+
  | pkey | cnt |
  +------+-----+
  | no_x | 3   |
  | no_z | 2   |
  | no_y | 2   |
  +------+-----+
  ```
- a final union of the two tables gives a result of

  ```
  +------+-----+
  | pkey | cnt |
  +------+-----+
  | no_x | 3   |
  | no_z | 2   |
  | no_y | 2   |
  | x    | 1   |
  | z    | 2   |
  | y    | 2   |
  +------+-----+
  ```